# R: Linear Regression By Group (2 variables)

Tags: r

I have a dataset of corporate fundamentals. I want to regress variable `SALE` on `XOPR` and `PPEGT` by industry-year (industry is `SIC`).

So I need the coefficients (and the coefficients only) on the following:
`SALE ~ XOPR, PPEGT` by `SIC` and `date`. I am really not sure how to do this in R. I tried using the data.table package but I'm having trouble figuring out how to regress by two variables.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The syntax for regressing on two variables is `SALE ~ XOPR + PPEGT`

Comment: Yep,, that's no problem - it's the by group thing that is throwing me off. I need the regressions by industry-year.

Comment: This is too broad of a question. Please post some code and formulate a specific question. Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dplyr package to group by

```
library(dplyr)
##rough-syntax is as follows
grouped_data = orginal_data %>% group_by(SIC, Date)  

library(forecast)
pred <- lm(SALE ~ XOPR + PPEGT)
pred #should give you the output of coefficients
```